# Training loss is not reduced in DNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'd like to train a model to learn the relationship between a feature with shape (1,3751) and a label with shape (1,1).

It looks simple enough so I just used a two dense layer DNN as the model type and hope the trained model can help me do good enough predictions. The prediction value, however, is way off and I noticed that the loss during training is not reduced at all.

I've tried different methods like changing the learning rate or increase the hidden layers in the model, but none of those worked.

The following is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import with_statement

import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  """Model function for Estimator."""

  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [1,3751])

  first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(input_layer, 1000, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  third_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer,10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  predictions = tf.layers.dense(third_hidden_layer, 1)


  # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.PREDICT`.
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions={"ages": predictions})


  labels_first_row = tf.reshape(labels[1], [1,-1])
  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels_first_row, predictions)

  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
      learning_rate=params["learning_rate"])
  train_op = optimizer.minimize( 
      loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

  # Calculate root mean squared error as additional eval metric
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(
          tf.cast(labels_first_row, tf.float32), predictions)
  }

  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train_op,
      eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):
  train_file = "training_data.csv"
  test_file = "test_data.csv"

  train_features_interim = pd.read_csv(train_file, usecols=['current'])
  train_features_numpy = np.asarray(train_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
  train_labels_interim = pd.read_csv(train_file, usecols=['plo_tox'])
  train_labels_numpy = np.asarray(train_labels_interim, dtype=np.float32)

  model_params = {"learning_rate": LEARNING_RATE}

  # Instantiate Estimator
  nn = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=model_params, 
  model_dir='/tmp/nmos_self_define')

  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_features_numpy},
      y=train_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 3751,
      num_epochs= None,
      shuffle=False)

  # Train
  nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10000)

  test_features_interim = pd.read_csv(test_file, usecols = ['current'])
  test_features_numpy = np.asarray(test_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
  test_labels_interim = pd.read_csv(test_file, usecols=['plo_tox'])
  test_labels_numpy = np.asarray(test_labels_interim, dtype=np.float32)

  # Score accuracy
  test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": test_features_numpy},
      y=test_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 3751,
      num_epochs= None,
      shuffle=False)

  ev = nn.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn, steps = 500)
  print("Loss: %s" % ev["loss"])
  print("Root Mean Squared Error: %s" % ev["rmse"])

  prediction_file = "Tensorflow_prediction_data.csv"

  predict_features_interim = pd.read_csv(prediction_file, usecols=['current'])
  predict_features_numpy = np.asarray(predict_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)

  # Print out predictions
  predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x= {"x": predict_features_numpy},
      num_epochs=1,
      batch_size = 3751,
      shuffle=False)

  predictions = nn.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)
  for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
    print("Prediction %s: %s" % (i + 1, p["ages"]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
  parser.add_argument(
      "--train_data", type=str, default="", help="Path to the training data.")
  parser.add_argument(
      "--test_data", type=str, default="", help="Path to the test data.")
  parser.add_argument(
      "--predict_data",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Path to the prediction data.")
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Since I am just a beginner of machine learning, I figured that it would probably be better for me to ask for opinions from someone who know better. I think I have a few knobs to tweak but I am not very sure about them, please provide any advice you think useful.

1. Change the activation function
2. Use regularization ( please let me know how to do it properly )
3. Do some feature manipulation
4. Increase the hidden layers and nodes
5. Increase the training set sizes ( Now I only have 900 sets of data for training, is this enough?)

My input data sheet looks like this :
[image]

Are there any other options? Thanks in advance for providing any kinds of thoughts.

Comment: You could briefly describe your data ?

Comment: Input data : 900 sets of input sets, each with 3751 float32 numbers.
Output data : 1 float32 number correspond to one set (3751 numbers) of input data.

Comment: Hi @MohanRadhakrishnan, please refer to my newly added figures in the post about my data sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You say that the batch size is `3751`, and in `model_fn` you're reshaping your input features to shape `(1, 3751)`, which doesn't make sense because `tf.layers.dense` expects each batch and each feature in the first and the second dimensions, respectively.

Comment: I newly added my input excel sheets in my post. I took the "current" column as the feature and "plo_tox" column as the label. As you can see in the figure (though only partially) that every 3751 rows of "current" corresponds to 1 "plo_tox", that's why I am taking the batch size of 3751.

I want to take in 3751 rows at a time for the feature (current) and train the model for the relationship between 3751 features and 1 label.

Did I do wrong with the batch size thing?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the `tf.reshape` in `model_fn` doesn't look good to me. You could simply try to set `input_layer` to `features["x"]` (assuming that `features["x"]` has shape `(3751, 1)`). Your network might still not work (i.e. you have a huge network for only one input feature, and the values of "current" are very small), but at least you will fix something that is conceptually wrong from my point of view.

Comment: As you suggested, I changed my input data into 3751 data as one input feature sets and 1 data as output lable. And I train the model with 1 batch ( data shape (1,3751)) at a time. Still as you predicted I cannot have proper results even with me trying different kinds of activation functions. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The shape of the data should be `(3751, 1)` (not `(1,3751)`). I don't think I can provide further help (this depends a lot on the problem), but you should try to standardize your data (i.e. make each column have mean 0 and std 1), and try a much smaller network (you only have one input feature).

Comment: Now I take 1 batch at a time. Each batch would have 1 row with 3751 columns, thus creating the shape of feature to be (1, 3751). Does the shape of input features being  (1, 3751) or (3751, 1) matter?

Comment: Yes, it does. If you are using the TF dense layer, the shape should be `(batch_size, nb_features)`.